Insert GRIB2 File into PSQL Postgis database
so I'm trying to insert a GRIB2 file into a postgreSQL database with postgis installed. I know that I can get the raster with raster2pgsql into the database but I'm looking for a way to get the whole GRIB2 file into a table without losing the metadata. I was thinking about trying to write the binary content inside of a table/column but so far it's not working right because everytime I select the content it can't be read as grib2 file again.
I used a python script that reads the binary file using psycopg2 and writes it to the database and also some SQL commands like copy but it's still the wrong format.
Thank you for any advice.
I tried to copy the content of a GRIB2 file via script or command line to a PSQL Postgis DB and expected the SELECT content FROM gribtable to give a the exact content of a GRIB2 file back so it can be read by grib_ls / grib_dump.
